# Regexextract behaving unexpectedly

Tags: regex, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I am trying to extract a (variable) substring from a longer result output string in a cell.

```
=SPLIT(TRIM(REGEXEXTRACT($Z3,“.(?s)+\([R][1][-][1][M]\)\s+\w+\s+\w+\s+\w+\s+[-]+\s+(.*)“)),1)
```

Typical content of cell `Z3` is:

> (F1-1D) Unique identifier schemes found [‘url’], (R1-1M) Resource type specified - webpage, (R1.2-1M) Found date-related picture information, (A1-2M) Access to metadata found: slurp

I want to extract the word between `-` and `,` following `(R1-1M)`.
In this example it is `webpage`.
The string can contain any number of the comma-separated elements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(TRIM(FLATTEN(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(IFNA(REGEXEXTRACT(
 IFERROR(SPLIT(A1:A, ",")), "\(R1-1M\).+- (.+)"))),,9^9))))
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

**EDIT**

Taking a better look at the OP's question

> I want to extract the word between - and , following (R1-1M).
> In this example it is webpage.
> The string can contain any number of the comma-separated elements.

I believe the whole formula can be further simplified to

```
=REGEXEXTRACT($A$3, "- (\w+),")
```

---

Original answer

You can try the following

```
=REGEXEXTRACT($A$3, "(\w+),[ \(R1\.2\-1M\)]")
```

or even

```
=REGEXEXTRACT($A$3, "[\(R1\-1M\)] (\w+),")
```

*(Do adjust ranges to your needs)*

[image]

Comment: its not granted there is (R1.2-1M) in csv

Comment: @player0 In that case the second formula should suffice the OP.

Comment: Thanks. This works well in some cases, but when there is no "(R1-1M)", it can trigger on e.g. the presence of "(F1-02D) Persistence identifier scheme - handle, "
giving "handle" has a result. I do not understand why.

Comment: Have you tried the edited, further simplified answer? If still in need, please share some more examples

Comment: Also, when there is a
"(F3-01M) Number of object content identifier found - 1, " in the cell, it will return "1".

Comment: I tried =REGEXEXTRACT($A$3, "[\(R1\-1M\)] (\w+),")
The first alternative 
=REGEXEXTRACT($A$3, "(\w+),[ \(R1\.2\-1M\)]")
requires that the last word before the comma is just before R1.2-1M... which is not necessarily true.

Comment: *"I tried..."* Well...? Did any of the 3 formulas work for you? If not, please **do share** some more test data so as you can be easier helped. If yes, you can accept the answer. I do believe your formula is too convoluted for such a simple case.